# Como calcular a mediana de uma grande quantidade de valores?

Tags: python

Possuo uma lista com aproximadamente 1,5 milhões de valores e preciso definir qual é a mediana deste conjunto. Os valores estão armazenados em um arquivo, como *string*, entre aspas simples (ex.: `'155'`).

Quais as formas de eu calcular a mediana deste montante de valores?

**Obs.:** Não posso utilizar as funções prontas, tal como `min`, `max`, etc.

Comment: 1.5mi são 1500 ou um milhão e meio?

Comment: São aproximadamente 1 milhão e meio de linhas.

Comment: Daniel, tomei a liberdade para editar sua pergunta e deixá-la um pouco mais direta. Poderia confirmar para mim se por acaso não errei na interpretação e alterei a pergunta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não errou na interpretação e ficou muito melhor. Obrigado!

Comment: Veja [este código](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/201728/177320)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste tipo de problema temos que ter muito cuidado com tempo de execução e memória. Trabalhar com listas pode ser um problema. Por enquanto sugiro essa solução.

**1)** Ler o arquivo linha a linha e, enquanto lê, já adiciona os números em uma lista de maneira ordenada

Para isso, vamos usar esta função que coloca um numero em uma lista na posição ordenada.

```
def adiciona_na_ordem(lista, tamanho_lista, numero):
    for i in range(0, tamanho_lista):
        if numero < lista[i]:
            break
    else:
        i+=1
    return lista[:i]+[numero]+lista[i:]

>>> lista = [0,1,2,3]
>>> print (adiciona_na_ordem(lista, len(lista), 10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 10]
```

E ler o arquivo linha a linha:

```
entrada = open('dados.txt', 'r')

lista_ordenada = [int(entrada.readline())] #Para não inicializar a lista vazia
num_lidos = 1 #Evita usar len(lista_ordenada)
for linha in entrada:
    numero = int(linha)
    lista_ordenada = adiciona_na_ordem(lista_ordenada, num_lidos, numero)
    num_lidos += 1

entrada.close()
```

Um exemplo seria:

```
para uma entrada:
7
7
1
4
4
5
6
7

>>> print (lista_ordenada)
[1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
```

**2)** Pegar a mediana

```
if num_lidos % 2 == 1:
    mediana = lista_ordenada[num_lidos//2]
else:
    mediana = (lista_ordenada[num_lidos//2 -1]+lista_ordenada[num_lidos//2]) / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, as informações estão meio vagas e também não se sabe o formato do arquivo onde estão esses dados, com isso, posso te passar apenas uma ideia do que fazer.

**1)** Ler o arquivo e botar os valores numa lista(se o arquivo for .csv vai facilitar muito).

**2)** Transforma-los em intergers usando o *int()*.

**3)** Usar a função *sorted()* para ordenar a lista, exemplo [aqui](http://blog.alura.com.br/ordenando-listas-no-python/).

**4)** Calcular o tamanho total da lista usando a função *len()*.

**5)** Pegar o tamanho total da lista e calcula o resto da divisão desse número por 2 usando o sinal de *%*.

**6)** Se for par, você faz a média dos elementos centrais, se for impar a mediana é o elemento central da sua lista.

Comment: E fazer isso com 1,5 milhões de números? Parece inviável para mim.

Comment: Fica realmente pesado, concordo, mas na ausência de alternativa... Há maneiras de processar esse arquivo separadamente, tipo dividi-lo em X partes, ordenar, contar a ocorrência de casos e posteriormente tirar a conclusão... Mas aí já seria outro processo...

Answer (score 1):

Gostaria de sugerir outra abordagem. Se os números forem inteiros ou com poucas casas decimais, muitos deles podem se repetir, então podemos contar o numero de ocorrências de cada número um com um dicionário. Assim, não usamos tanta memória.

**1)** Lemos o arquivo linha a linha e fazemos um dicionário com as ocorrências ao mesmo tempo que mantemos uma lista com as chaves ordenadas (usaremos futuramente)

Função que coloca um numero em uma lista na posição ordenada:

```
def adiciona_na_ordem(lista, tamanho_lista, numero):
    for i in range(0, tamanho_lista):
        if numero < lista[i]:
            break
    else:
        i+=1
    return lista[:i]+[numero]+lista[i:]
```

Lemos linha a linha:

```
entrada = open('dados.txt', 'r')

primeiro_valor = int(entrada.readline())
ocorrencias = {primeiro_valor:1}
lista_chaves_ordenadas = [primeiro_valor]
num_linhas = 1

for linha in entrada:
    numero = int(linha)
    if numero in ocorrencias: #Se o numero ja esta no dicionario
        ocorrencias[numero] += 1
    else: #Se não está, adiciono em ocorrencias
        ocorrencias[numero] = 1
        #OU ocorrencias.update({numero:1})
        lista_chaves_ordenadas = adiciona_na_ordem(lista_chaves_ordenadas, len(lista_chaves_ordenadas), numero)

    num_linhas += 1

entrada.close()
```

Exemplo de como ficariam as variaveis:

```
para uma entrada:
7
7
1
4
4
5
6
7

>>> print (ocorrencias)
{7: 3, 1: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1}
>>> print (lista_chaves_ordenadas)
[1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

**2)** Agora calculamos a mediana percorrendo o dicionário na ordem das chaves ordenadas até que a soma das ocorrências chegue na metade

```
if num_linhas % 2 == 1: #Buscamos o elemento central
    num_elementos = 0
    for key in lista_chaves_ordenadas:
        num_elementos += ocorrencias[key]
        if num_elementos >= num_linhas/2:
            print (key)
            break

else: #media dos dois elementos centrais
    num_elementos = 0
    mediana = None
    for key in lista_chaves_ordenadas:
        num_elementos += ocorrencias[key]
        #Prox 2 ifs se os valores medianos forem chaves diferentes, ex: 5 e 6
        if num_elementos == num_linhas/2:
            mediana = key
        if num_elementos > num_linhas/2 and mediana != None:
            mediana += key
            print(mediana/2)
            break
        #Prox if se os valores medianos forem a mesma chave, ex: 6 e 6
        if num_elementos > num_linhas/2 and mediana == None:
            mediana = key
            print(key)
            break
```

Edit:
Se você utilizar pytho2.7, acho que o dicionário já fica ordenado, então não precisa da lista_chaves_ordenadas, basta fazer `for key, value in ocorrencias.iteritems():` em vez de `for key in lista_chaves_ordenadas:`. Mas tome cuidado com as divisões. Faça `/2.0` para não arredondar para inteiro